# How to draw routes in open street maps using Python/R?

Tags: python, r, maps, openstreetmap

I have data in the form of lattitude and longitude co-ordinates. I want to plot a route for those co-ordinates in OSM using either Python or R. Can somebody tell me where can I begin? I've not worked with OSM before.
For each user I've a route which is a set of lattitude and longitude co-ordinates, so I want to plot each user's routes.I would prefer python alternatives over R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the package RgoogleMaps.  The function `GetMap.OSM` will retrieve a map from Open Street Maps and then you can use the `PlotOnStaticMap` function with `FUN=lines` to plot a set of lines connecting the lat and long points.

The ggmap package can also do this using ggplot2 style graphics.  The `get_openstreetmap` in that package will download a map for you then use `ggmap` to plot the map and use the regular ggplot2 functions to add the routes on top.